# Modify HEIF metadata

Tags: macos, heif

I need to modify metadata data of HEIF files while preserving all other metadata data and images contained in the original file.

Preferably I would like to use XMP SDK for that, because it can preserve unknown metadata data fields and I already use it with other file formats, but any solution is acceptable.

I could not find how to do this with [nokiatech's GitHub repo](https://github.com/nokiatech/heif) or with Apple's API.

Comment: *Where* do you want to do this…? What system/language?

Comment: I work with C++/Objective C on macOS, but Swift or any other code that can be wrapped and used from these languages would be good.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question off the top of my head, but I just wanted to say that if you figure this out and make an app for doing this, I recommend the name "HEIFer." ;-)